# Jar executable with sqlite driver

Tags: java, sqlite, jar

I made a code that connects to my `sqlite` driver which is in the `CLASSPATH` and reads some database file. I want to create an executable which can be used on computers that don't have the `sqlite` driver.

If I do:

```
jar cvfe exec.jar main_class
```

I will get "class not found: org.sqlite.JDBC" when running with

```
java -jar exec.jar
```

What should I do to make the executable work?

Edit:
I don't know if it makes any difference, but this is the JDBC driver I use:

https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

Comment: Do you use maven/gradle for build your jar?

Comment: Can't I do this from command line? It should be easy, but I can't find it anywhere

Comment: You should include the driver *inside* the JAR. Are you doing that?

Comment: No. I'm not sure I know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the library inside the JAR. Maybe you don't know this, but JAR files are just ZIP files, so you can change their contents easily. Here are some quick instructions on how to do it. Assuming your JAR file is named `exec.jar`, and the JAR of the library you want to include (the JAR you downloaded) is `driver.jar`

1. Change your file name from `exec.jar` to `exec.zip`.
2. Extract all the contents of `exec.zip` into folder `exec/`
3. Change your library file name from `driver.jar` to `driver.zip`
4. Extract all the contents of `driver.zip` into folder `driver/`
5. Copy the contents of `driver/` into `exec/`, but **do not copy** the `META-INF` folder. If a pop-up asks if it's ok to merge the folders, click yes.
6. Compress all files in `exec/` into `exec.zip`
7. Rename `exec.zip` to `exec.jar` (replace the original).

You can include any java library inside a JAR using this method.

Comment: Just a few questions. The driver has only one jar file. Is that what should be in the org/sqlite folder? Or do I have to extract the driver.jar? I've done both, but when I try to use the final exec.jar file it says it's corrupted.

Comment: Extract the driver.jar. Inside, you will find a folder named `org`. Inside `org` you will find a folder named `sqlite`. Copy all the contents of `sqlite` into your `exec.jar/org/sqlite`.

Comment: I updated the answer, hopefully making it more clear. Actually all you need to do is merge the library jar with your jar.

Comment: It does work now. The corruption was not an serious issue. Thanks.

Comment: Also works if I add org/sqlite to my java directory after compilation and type 
jar cvfe exec.jar main_class *.class org

Answer (score 0):

Here is the doc:

```
C:\Windows\System32>jar /?
Illegal option: /
Usage: jar {ctxui}[vfmn0Me] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] files ...
```

And so I think the command you need is:

```
jar cvfe exec.jar main_class main_class
```

Comment: But how do I get the SQLite to work with the executable?

Comment: I suppose you just pass a -classpath arg to the above command that includes the location of the SQLite.jar file.  of course, this is a problem because you aren't extracting the executable .jar and so you wont be able to load the resource.   There is a way to handle it, just don't know the exact way.  There is a Maven plugin that will do it.