# Linking dependency with JAR

Tags: java

I have this folder structure:

```
|___main
| |___lib -> this folder contains my runnable jar file
| |___ext -> this folder contains dependency files (.jar) for the jar
|___log4j.properties -> here I have log4j.property file
```

How can I execute the JAR without `ClassNotFoundException` or any other error? I am using Eclipse Luna and this is a Java Project.

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer. I can only recommend you read about [the classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Comment: above mentioned is the folder structure, if i run java -cp is permanent it won't change.

Comment: You can include all the dependencies *inside* the jar file, and you will never get any `ClassNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can include all your dependencies *inside* your JAR file. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25853152/3718878) on how to do it.

There are also tools that automate this process, such as [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

Comment: what about log4j.properties?

Comment: @ShivaShiva You can definitely put your log4j.properties file into your jar. Log4j loads its configuration by searching the class path, so if you put in into the root of your jar, it should be found.

Comment: Add `log4j.properties` to your JAR file.

Comment: i want the log4j to be edited, i can't extract jar to edit log4j properties

Comment: @ShivaShiva Then supply the path to it with `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/log4j.properties`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7390591/2071828).

Comment: @Zenadix the answer you linked does this manually, surely you are not advocating that; its an absolutely terrible idea. Either explain how you would do this using a build tool, such as Maven or Ant, or turn this "answer" into a comment.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I strongly believe new Java programmers should learn to do this manually before learning to use build tools such as Maven or Ant. Doing so allows them to *understand* how Java really works.

Comment: While that's true, if you don't explain how to do it "right" almost immediately, they'll just persist in using a slow, inconsistent, laborious, accident-prone method forever, or worse, roll their own ad hoc build process.  Understanding how it works is good.  Doing it right is better.